# can i use Localhost and Ip adress at the same time on Elasticsearch 5.2

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

to get communication between 2 servers on Elasticsearch, i had to change network.host in the config file elasticsearch.yml  from

```
network.host: 'localhost'
```

to

```
network.host: '192.X.X.X'
```

Localhost is defaut host in bibliothek elasticsearch-py

i have a simple question!

can i use ip adress 192.X.X.X and localhost at the same time to get access to  plugin/elasticsearch-head-master.

The problem now is that i have to change default parameter "Localhost" to the ip adress 192.X.X.X in all bibliothek.

any advice please?

Thanks for help